# How to use dplyr (1.1.0) across() with list of functions using shared arguments

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, mutate, across

###### Quick set up with dummy data and functions

Load dplyr
`library(dplyr)`

Set up simple data frame with one column
`data <- data.frame(a = 1:5)`

Define two functions
`newfun1 <- function(x, val) {x + val}`
`newfun2 <- function(x, val) {x * val}`

Store functions as named list
`usefuns <- stats::setNames(as.list(c(newfun1, newfun2)), c("fun1", "fun2"))`

[named list of functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hifso.png)

###### Goal: Apply each function in `usefuns` to `data` column `a`, specifying the `val` argument should be `100`

Using `dplyr < 1.1.0`, I can make it work easily:

`data %>% mutate(across(.col = a, .fns = usefuns, val = 100))`

[results of previous code; data frame with three columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aA4as.png)

However, using `dplyr 1.1.0`, I get this warning:

> The `...` argument of `across()` is deprecated as of dplyr 1.1.0.
> Supply arguments directly to `.fns` through an anonymous function instead.
> #Previously
> `across(a:b, mean, na.rm = TRUE)` 
> #Now
> `across(a:b, ~(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))`

I can make it work with `dplyr 1.1.0` using:

`data %>% mutate(across(.col = a, .fns = list(fun1 = ~newfun1(.x, val = 100), fun2 = ~newfun2(.x, val = 100))))`

or even

`data %>% mutate(across(.col = a, .fns = list(fun1 = ~usefuns$fun1(.x, val = 100), fun2 = ~usefuns$fun2(.x, val = 100))))`

[results of previous code; data frame with three columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkdXR.png)

but I know there must be a simpler way. In the real-world scenario that I'm using this, the number of functions contained in `usefuns` will be variable, and there are several more arguments, but the arguments being passed to each function will always be the same.

I think I'm missing something relatively simple and have already wasted too much time experimenting. Any pointers are appreciated!

---

As an added note, `val` may have differing values each time it is used:

Set up simple data frame with three columns

`data <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 6:10, c = 11:15)`

Example of more complicated application of functions using `dplyr < 1.1.0`:

`data %>% mutate(across(.col = c(a, b), .fns = usefuns, val = 100), across(.col = c, .fns = usefuns, val = 200))`

I've tried variations on listing and naming functions, how they are stored and called on, started going down the path of using `purrr` but couldn't get it as close to working as I did with the code provided above... I'm wondering if the `partial()` function could come into play, but can't quite figure out how/if that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass your function list to `purrr::map`/`lapply` and then use `purrr::partial` within and pass the value of `val`.

```
library(purrr)
data %>% 
    mutate(across(.col = a,
                  .fns = purrr::map(usefuns, 
                                    purrr::partial, 
                                    val = 100)))
```

Or for the more complex example:

```
data <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 6:10, c = 11:15)
data %>% 
    mutate(across(.col = c(a, b), 
                  .fns = map(usefuns, partial, val = 100)),
           across(.col = c,
                  .fns = map(usefuns, partial, val = 200)))
  a  b  c a_fun1 a_fun2 b_fun1 b_fun2 c_fun1 c_fun2
1 1  6 11    101    100    106    600    211   2200
2 2  7 12    102    200    107    700    212   2400
3 3  8 13    103    300    108    800    213   2600
4 4  9 14    104    400    109    900    214   2800
5 5 10 15    105    500    110   1000    215   3000
```