# Using the `...` argument of `across()` for a list of functions in tidyverse/R

Tags: r

I am attempting to apply multiple functions (stored as a list) to variables in a tibble using the across() function. Apparently in the new version of dplyr (1.1.0), passing multiple arguments using the `...` argument is now deprecated. The solution offered in the documentation (to use labmda/anonymous functions) is only useful for a single function....not a list of functions.

Below is an example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df <- tibble(x = c(1,2),
             y = c(3, 4))

fns <- list(minus_y = function(x,y) x - y,
            plus_y = function(x,y) x + y)

# What I used to do, but is now deprecated
df %>%
  mutate(across(x, fns, y))

## A tibble: 2 x 4
#      x     y x_minus_y x_plus_y
#  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#1     1     3        -2        4
#2     2     4        -2        6
```

This now gives the below warning:

```
Warning message:
There was 1 warning in `mutate()`.
i In argument: `across(x, fns, y)`.
Caused by warning:
! The `...` argument of `across()` is deprecated as of dplyr 1.1.0.
Supply arguments directly to `.fns` through an anonymous function instead.

  # Previously
  across(a:b, mean, na.rm = TRUE)

  # Now
  across(a:b, \(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))
This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was generated.
```

The suggestion does not work for a list of functions.

I did find this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76408437/how-to-use-dplyr-1-1-0-across-with-list-of-functions-using-shared-arguments), which recommends using the `purrr::partial` function in conjuction with the `purrr::map` function. However, this does not work in my situation because my additional argument is a column in my data:

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(x, map(fns,
                       partial,
                       y = y)))
#Error in `mutate()`:
#i In argument: `across(x, map(fns, partial, y = y))`.
#Caused by error in `across()`:
#! Can't compute column `x_minus_y`.
#Caused by error:
#! object 'y' not found
#Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Maybe I am going about this all wrong and am open to suggestions. How should you apply multiple functions that take the same multiple arguments?

Comment: I also find their deprecation and planned removal of support for `...`, as that's a great way to do something like what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df <- tibble(x = c(1,2),
             y = c(3, 4))
# if you prefer to keep your functions general and wrap them then
fns <- list(minus_y = function(x,y) x - y,
            plus_y = function(x,y) x + y)

df |> mutate(across(x,map(fns,
                          \(f)partial(f,y=unlist(pick(y)))))) 

# otherwise you can rewrite your input functions to more 
# clearly illustrate how they work
fns <- list(minus_y = function(x) x - unlist(pick(y)),
            plus_y = function(x) x + unlist(pick(y)))
# and therefore use them without map and partial
df |> mutate(across(x,fns))
```

Answer (score 2):

When I tried this with the latest version 1.1.2 of dplyr on CRAN it worked and there was no deprecation message but assuming that a future version of dplyr does deprecate dot dot dot

**1)** This works without `partial` but involves defining `fns` within `across`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(x, list(minus_y = function(x) x - y,
                        plus_y = function(x) x + y)))
```

or

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(x, list(minus_y = function(x, y_ = y) x - y_,
                        plus_y = function(x, y_ = y) x + y_)))
```

**2)** Another possibility is to use fmutate/across from the collapse package.  `fmutate` uses its own internally defined `across`.

```
library(collapse)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  fmutate(across(x, fns, y))
```

**3)** Another approach is to define fns_q using `quote`:

```
fns_q <- quote(list(minus_y = function(x) x - y,
             plus_y = function(x) x + y))
df %>% mutate(across(x, !!!fns_q))
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this solution? With `sapply()` you can pass a list of functions as the input. Inside the anonymous function of `sapply()`, you can pass each function in the list and use the same df variables as inputs. Then you can `cbind()` the `sapply()` results to your data if needed.

```
cbind.data.frame(df, sapply(fns, function(z){z(df$x,df$y)}))
```

#### edit to make names represent variables that were passed in

```
s1 <- sapply(fns, function(z){z(df$x,df$y)})

colnames(s1) <- paste0("x_",colnames(s1))
cbind.data.frame(df, s1)
```

Comment: I think the point is to use the "1 or more" functionality of `across` column selection (I'm happy to be wrong here)

Comment: ah ok I see, I saw the last sentence in the OP as they might be open to other suggestions but if it has to stay in the tidyverse I will try to modify

Comment: Yes, thank you @Mike. I am open to anything. Yours does work. Its a bit clunkier and would prefer staying in the tidyverse. Also, the resulting names isnt quite convenient long term. across() would return a combination of the col and functions which is handy if i wanted to apply it to an additional column.

Comment: ok great I edited the answer to address the name issue, but it is still clunky